# Assign to each user a color

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chat

I am currently creating a web-chat and whenever a message is displayed in the chat-box, the user that sent the message is displayed and identified with a color. For every user I create a class and assign a value to the color style with the above function.

```
newHTML = '';

$.each(data, function(index, element) {

    $('.user_' + element.senderId).attr("style","color:" + randColor());

    newHTML = newHTML + '<div id="boxMsg"><b><span class="user_' + element.senderId + '">' 
                      + element.senderId + '</b></span></br>' + element.message + '&nbsp&nbsp<span class="dateMsg">' + dateTime.substring(11, 16) + '</span></div>';    

    });

$('#chatbox').append(newHTML);           
},
```

A JSON protocol is used to extract all the information concerning the message displayed on the chat. But still it doesn't work and all the usernames are black. Do you know what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

EDIT: thanks to @Evan I solved the first part and the function to assign a random color works. But still, only the first and the third member of the chat color changes. The others are still black. Anyway, I leave the code for the function randColor().

```
function randColor(){
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                }
                return color;
            };
```

EDIT.2: I have corrected the function to reflect more the one I am working on.

Comment: I have just applied Evan's correction.

Comment: don't change your code in the question. Mark Evan's answer as correct

Comment: @Davide: You can't use `<= 6` - you can use `<= 5` because arrays are zero-based.

Comment: @Nathan I wanted to change it because I am still having problems with it.

Comment: @Evan yes, I applied your correction! Thank you man :) But still there are problems displaying the different colors.

Comment: @Davide then make sure when you edit your code you update the question to reflect it.

Comment: @NathanKoop Yes man, thanks for the tip! I am currently updating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue and correctly assign a color to each user. This is how the final code looks like:

```
function randColor(){
                var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
                var color = '#';
                for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
                }
                return color;
            };
            userColor = [];
            userColor.push(randColor());
            $('.user_' + element.senderId).css("color", userColor);     

            // Create box messages of the other users           
            var dateTime = element.timestamp;
            newHTML = '<div id="boxMsg"><b><span class="user_' + element.senderId +'" style="color:'+ userColor +'">'+ element.senderId + '</span></b></br>' 
                      + element.message + '&nbsp&nbsp<span class="dateMsg">' + dateTime.substring(11, 16) + '</span></div>';    

            $('#chatBox').append(newHTML);
```

What I did was to create an array, store the obtained colors inside it and finally assign to each class of each user one element inside this array. Thanks to all of you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

`for (var i = 0; i <= nUsers.length; i++ )`

should be

`for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ )`

to form a hex color. It should always be 6 (or 3 for short hex colors).

Comment: Apparently there is an improvement! Thank you! But still I am getting colored the first and the third message of the chat.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.attr("style",properties)`

If you need to change de background color use the property "background-color":

```
$('.user_' + element.senderId).attr("style","background-color:" + randColor());
```

Or, if you need to change de font color use the property "color":

```
$('.user_' + element.senderId).attr("style","color:" + randColor());
```

Comment: Can you put the values generated from "randColor()" here?

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your HTML-->

```
var newHTML = '';
 newHTML = newHTML + '<div id="boxMsg"><b><span class="user_' + element.senderId + '">' + element.senderId + '</b></span></br>' + element.message + '&nbsp&nbsp<span class="dateMsg">' + dateTime.substring(11, 16) + '</span></div>';

$('#chatbox').append(newHTML);
```

The "bold" tag closes before the span.

Fix it -->

```
newHTML = newHTML + '<div id="boxMsg"><b><span class="user_' + element.senderId + '">' + element.senderId + '</span></b></br>' + element.message + '&nbsp&nbsp<span class="dateMsg">' + dateTime.substring(11, 16) + '</span></div>';
```

Other then that, you can call the randomColor when you build the HTML, instead calling it after with jquery... (and you won't need a special class)-->

```
newHTML = newHTML + '<div id="boxMsg"><b><span style="color:'+randColor()+'">' + element.senderId + '</span></b></br>' + element.message + '&nbsp&nbsp<span class="dateMsg">' + dateTime.substring(11, 16) + '</span></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction man! But apparently still nothing. I am still experiencing the same problem: if I place $('#chatbox').append(newHTML);  inside each() function, only user 1 and 3 get their name colored. Otherwise nothing happens.